# How do I convert into Brahmin when I am already a converted Hindu?

Tags: brahmins, conversion

My ancestors were Brahmins but they were forced to be Muslims, so I am a born Muslim but I already converted to Hinduism and I'm a pure vegetarian and I have knowledge of Vedas and Mahabharata. So can I get my caste of my ancestors and poonal back?

Comment: Welcome although your question is related to Hinduism , it is out of the scope of this site as this is personal advice question. We suggest to consult a good priest near to your place and take expert priests  advice they can only provide all necessary information and  procedure required for that.

Comment: It is said that those Brahmin families who abandoned sacred thread ceremony for continuously three generations, ceased to become Brahmanas along with their descendants. So in simple terms, you cannot.

Comment: Perform Vratyastoma Yajna